How to implement launching Intent with inputs and also get response in .net Maui for both Android and iOS
I wish to implement the ability to launch Google pay app from my .Net Maui app. The documentation from google provides implementation in Java which

builds URI,
Creates Intent,
StartsActivityForResult to launch Gpay App with inputs
also get the response from the Intent.

    Uri uri =
    new Uri.Builder()
        .scheme("upi")
        .authority("pay")
        .appendQueryParameter("pa", "your-merchant-vpa@xxx")
        .appendQueryParameter("pn", "your-merchant-name")
        .appendQueryParameter("mc", "your-merchant-code")
        .appendQueryParameter("tr", "your-transaction-ref-id")
        .appendQueryParameter("tn", "your-transaction-note")
        .appendQueryParameter("am", "your-order-amount")
        .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
        .appendQueryParameter("url", "your-transaction-url")
        .build();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setPackage(GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE);

But how can this be implemented in .Net Maui for Android and iOS. If it is Platform specific implementation, then any example of how to create this Intent/start etc. will be of great help.

https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/android/in-app-payments
https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/ios/in-app-payments


For iOS you simply create the gpay: uri and open it. This will launch the gpay app. There is no way to automatically return to your app from the gpay app on iOS.

@Paulw11 if user manually toggles back is fine. But will I get ActivityResult with response message from that gpay app?

No. There is no communication back from gpay. You would need to have some other way of determining that the payment was made. Perhaps it is is different in your country, but I would think it is very rare for iPhone users to even have Google pay set up.
